# I'm trying to use a formula to calculate a percentage based on hours completed/ items done compared to hours estimated/ items total

Tags: excel

As the title says, I'm trying to calculate a percentage that represents productivity. I have a formula that almost works to change the colors (conditional formatting) but it seems to work in reverse. I can't figure out how to make it work and I'm hoping its something simple and I'm just dense after working on it for a day.

Below is my formula that I have so far.

```
=VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3))*(J18/K18)/D18>95%
```

As I said, I hope that it's stupid simple to make it work and I'm just being stupid.

This is the cells in question in the event the clarification of seeing it will make more sense:

[image]

**Links to pages I hoped would help:**
[1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191908/how-to-calculate-a-percentage): Not quiet right.
[2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955990/php-calculate-percentage-on-multiple-items): VBA so not it either.
[3rd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214713/challenging-formula-to-calculate-amount-of-hours-based-on-several-criteria): Again just not something I can pull enough from.

Comment: `=(D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(J18/K18)`?  Also... `80/5` is `16` so this is exactly `200%` = `16/8`.

Comment: Sadly not (I appreciate the edit by the way). It is better, but not quiet there. It seems to be working in reverse order now (or something like that). 16 Hours to complete 1 task gives me green (sounds good), but 17 Hours changes it to yellow, and 18+ changes it to red.
Also, regarding the total estimated time per task taking 20 hours, 2 in 16 is slightly better than the 200% but that number isn't important with this. :D

Comment: `17` hours would give you `188.235%` (the more hours it takes to complete the less productive, the smaller the percentage). `18` hours would yield `177.778%`. `32` would be `100.00%`. Put that formula in your sheet and mess with the numbers to understand what your output is then do your conditional formatting based on your findings. The problem is either your assumptions about the output of productivity percentage or your conditional formatting (or my understanding of what math you are after, but this feels like it's spitting out a percentage of productivity compared to bid).

Comment: I will try to clarify slightly: I have been tasked with highlighting production for a given task that is `above 95%` (based on the actual work done/ completed compared to the estimated hours) in green. `90% up to 95%` in yellow, and `89% and below` in red.

I'm not saying that what I'm expecting isn't off or how I'm trying to go about it isn't wrong. I've been messing with it most of yesterday an I'm if nothing else out of ideas (though your initial comment was a huge help). The `16` hours is simply an `8` hour day for `2` employees).

Comment: I cannot follow this.  I believe that what you may be looking for is the actual hours per item to be less than 95% of the bid rate.  Thus, if the bid rate is 20 hours per item, you want 19 hours or less for the actual.  In other words, .95*(D18/E18)>(J18/K18), which gives me .95>(E18*J18)/(K18*D18) which is identical to your formula with the greater than/less than sign reversed.  I think that is what you think is occurring, so that may be your problem.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. It seems that I have a deeper issue than what I thought.
I edited my formula to reflect yours, first by changing the direction of the sign and then by typing yours in. Your way work almost. It's better for sure, but now there is no mid range so I'm not sure what I screwed up there. I guess I need to go back to the drawing board to see if there is a better way to do this so that I don't continue to waste your time. I do thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: In your examples here your productivity percent is `200%`. So it would be green. It will continue to be green until that `16` hours is around `34` hours where your conditional formatting will switch to Yellow. Once it hits `36` hours it will switch to Red. Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: If what I just wrote matches your expectations, then a conditional formatting formula for "Green" would look like: `=(D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(J18/K18)>.95`, yellow would be `=AND((D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(J18/K18)=>.90, (D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(J18/K18)<=.95)`, and red would be `=(D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(J18/K18)<.90` (remember we are dealing with decimals here so there is an entire gulf of numbers between `89%` and `90%` that you have to factor in).

Comment: Again... tinker with these in your spreadsheet so you can see what numbers they are spitting out (dropping the inequality). Or leaving the inequality in your cell formula you can see if it spits out True/False and matches your expectiations. Trying to build and debug this complex formula in your conditional formula leaves too many variables in for troubleshooting.

Comment: That is what I'm seeing. I guess that it isn't what I need though (I thought I did). Maybe I should have used another cell reference that uses feet instead.
Our guys won't work more than `20` hours a day on a task and sometimes less before switching. If they work `20` hours on a task consisting of `100ft` of material over `80 hours` but only get in `10ft`, that would need to be red. If they met the goal of more than `95%', then green, and `90% - 95%`, yellow.
As I said, I have made a bigger mistake in my thinking than the operation of the formula. Your reply was correct for my provided info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some outside help, I was able to get this working. Below is the code that works for my setup with conditional formatting.

```
=(D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(F18/G18)>0.95
=(D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(F18/G18)>=0.9
=(D18/VALUE(LEFT(E18,LEN(E18)-3)))/(F18/G18)<0.9
```